# How to use different string literals in PINE plot on trading view?

Tags: plot, text, pine-script

I have plot defined like this:

```
plotshape(xvalue, location=location.absolute, style=shape.labeldown, color=red, size=size.tiny, text ="Upper")
```

Problem here is with part text="Upper".
I wanted to allow user to shorten label so it can be "Upper" or "U".
This usualy can be done with something like this:

```
text = label ? "U" : "Upper"
```

Where "label" is true/false for shorter strings.

Problem is PINE isn't accepting it and error is something like "You must use string literals with 'text='".
https://www.tradingview.com/wiki/Literals#String_Literals

Is there a way around it so user can change plot text on fly?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Mikeyy. Good job on a well formulated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that *pine-script* does not accept string variables as plot labels. So the answer is that you cannot change the label from a script. It has to be *hard-coded*. The only workaround is to define another completely different plot using the other label in it.

Comment: So only workaround is to polute code with more redudant code which will default to "na" when variable is false. :) Thank you.