# Cannot use function for plot style, but works for plot color

Tags: pine-script

```
//@version=4
study("PlayGround", overlay=true)

f_color() => color.lime
f_style() => plot.style_line

plot(close, color=f_color())
plot(high,  style=f_style())
```

This script does not compile.
It throws error `Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined`.

Reason seems to be the use of function `f_style()` for the plot style.
I don't understand why that doesn't work.

I've found a related question [Why is true / false logic on “style=” not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52720653/why-is-true-false-logic-on-style-not-working).
The accepted answer suggests that this should be possible in Pine v4.

Answer (score 0):

Using a function for parameters requiring an argument of *input* form (the `style=` parameter requires an *input integer*) sometimes seems to prevent the compiler from keeping track of the fact that the function returns an acceptable form.

You can work around the problem by de-functionalizing the code. Except for the function, these all work:

```
//@version=4
study("PlayGround", overlay=true)

lineStyle = input(true)

f_color() => color.lime
f_style() => plot.style_line

style2 = lineStyle ? 0 : 6
style3 = lineStyle ? plot.style_line : plot.style_circles
style4 = plot.style_line

plot(close, color=f_color())
plot(high,  style=style3)
```

> I have added the example to a similar bug report we had already created.

Comment: Are those bug reports published somewhere?

Comment: Not yet. An ongoing list of known problems is planned for the usrman. No ETA yet, though.